# UIButton's IBAction method execute after delay in Swift

Tags: iphone, swift, uiscrollview, uibutton, delay

I have 4 `UIButtons` in a `UIScrollView`. The view hierarchy is like:

```
UIViewController-> UIView-> UIScrollView-> UIView-> UIView-> UIButton
```

I have connected the `IBAction` for respected `UIButton` with `TouchupInside` from `UIStoryboard`.
My Issue is when I click on `UIButton`, it gets highlighted, but the respected `IBAction` method is not getting called at the time. The action is been called after I select any other control like `UITextField` or any other editable control. I am unable to understand the issue.
I have tried to add the action to the `UIButton` programmatically also like:

```
self.newProductNotifBtn?.addTarget(self, action: #selector(notifCheckMarkBtnClicked), forControlEvents: .TouchUpInside)
```

But the result is same. No action on the method is executing at the same time it is been selected.

The suggestions are appreciated.

Comment: are you sure you've added it for touchUpInside and not another selector?

Comment: Yes, I have checked it twice.

Comment: It could be that you may be triggering the scrollviews viewDidBeginScrolling event rather than your buttons touchUpInside event (or any other events you may have on your views)

Comment: Is it possible to show more of your code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you all for you kind response and time.
After searching while I found my answer. Here I add my answer just to get someone help.
I had a silly mistake. The issue was not with the scrollview. 
I took a **tap gesture recognizer** in both storyboard and programatically. Which was make delay in button execution.
I removed it from both which make my code run perfectly and without any delay.

Thank you once again.